# Spark Scala : how to display same rows of dataframe, that differ in one column, only once with all different elements

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that produces a .csv as below :

[image]

All records differ in column "ncid" but all the other columns appear more than once. So I want my .csv to be exported as follows :

[image]

Comment: please add input and output data as text and not as an image. and also add what have you tried so far.

Comment: Also, does all the column have two values?,what if there is more or less than two values for each?

Comment: Provide the code you have used, so that can help you on this

Comment: The aforementioned .csv is after extracting the columns I want from a big file. I care only for these 5 columns. From all the records I care for those that appear in the file having the 4 first (last_name,first_name,middle_name and res_city_desc) more than once and differ only in "ncid". I tried to make it work through sqlContext.sql with group by and also directly with dataframe operations such as groupBy but I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have two values for all the rows you can `groupBy` and `collect` as list and create new columns.

```
df.groupBy("last_name", "first_name", "middle_name", "res_city_desc")
  .agg(collect_list($"ncid") as "ncid")
  .withColumn("ncid_1", $"ncid".getItem(0))
  .withColumn("ncid_2", $"ncid".getItem(1))
  .drop("ncid")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+-------+
|last_name|first_name|middle_name|res_city_desc|ncid1  |ncid2  |
+---------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+-------+
|ACCARDI  |JAMES     |SAMUEL     |BANNER ELK   |EL83935|AF25369|
|ADAMS    |THOMAS    |PAUL       |BOONE        |EL87042|EL50719|
+---------+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: There are rows with more than 2 values (actually up to 6).

Comment: @T_LongJ so do you want to add add 6 more columns? and what if there is now value for some rows? Any way the process would be same as above

Comment: Yes the process will be the same. You are right @koiralo. Thank you!